# Tidyverse summarize: a new summary variable within each iteration

Tags: r, tidyverse, summarize

I do have a problem that i just can't seem so solve.

Say I have a loop like the one provided by the minimal working example below. 
What I want R to do, is to create a new "summary" ( in this example "dogfood_items", "catfood_items", and "fishfood_items") variable for each iteration, i.e. I can't get the expression "summarize(str_c(food[i], "items", sep="_") = sum(items))" to work. 
Defining, an interim variable ( for example a <- str_c(food[i], "items", sep="_") ) and then writing summarize(a=sum(items) unfortunately also doesn't work.

What bugs me, is that "str_c(food[1], "items", "sep="_") standing on its own does work totally fine. It does not work within summarize(...).

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this working?

Please don't be to harsh on me. I'm pretty new to R.

Best wishes, David.

```
library(tidyverse)

food <- c("dogfood", "catfood", "fishfood")
output <- list()

data <- tribble(
  ~items, ~cost, ~staff, ~foodtype,
  100, 200, 11, "dogfood", 
  120, 20, 12, "dogfood",
  40, 120, 12, "catfood", 
  10, 12, 13, "fishfood",
)

data # view data

for (i in seq_along(food))
  output[[i]] <- data %>%
  filter(foodtype==food[i]) %>%
  summarise(str_c(food[i], "items", sep="_")=sum(items)) # the problem is here !
```

Comment: Are you trying to sum items by foodtype? There may be a better solution than a loop, such as `group_by()`.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to name the columns on the lhs of assignment, use `:=` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
output <- vector('list', length(food))
for (i in seq_along(food)) {
   output[[i]] <- data %>%
   filter(foodtype==food[i]) %>%
   summarise(!! str_c(food[i], "items", sep="_") := sum(items))
 }

output
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  dogfood_items
#          <dbl>
#1           220

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  catfood_items
#          <dbl>
#1            40

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  fishfood_items
#           <dbl>
#1             10
```

---

It may be easier to do a group by `sum` operation

```
data %>%
     group_by(foodtype) %>%
     summarise(out = sum(items))
```

Comment: Dear akrun, thank you so much. I haven been spending many hours on this problem. You're my personal hero. Thanks, this is what I have been looking for.

Comment: @David thank you for the kind messages.  Glad to know that it helps you